# Using ­@Contract with Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, java-annotations

I'm trying to use the `@Contract` annotation of IntelliJ but in Android Studio. I can't import it, it's not there. On the [website explaining it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html), it's said to add `<installation folder>/lib/annotations.jar` to the project's classpath using the Project Structure dialog, however I didn't found how to that.

Is there anyway to use the `@Contract` annotation on Android Studio?

Comment: The annotation jar is available in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0). Try to include `compile group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '13.0'` in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotations jar is available in [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0). Just add  `compile group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '13.0'` in your build.gradle file.